# geometry.transform() removes the drawn feature in OpenLayers

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, linestring, transform

I have a simple OL-based map with the default `EPSG:3857` projection and an interaction which lets me draw a `LineString` on the map. Then, I have an event listener registered on the `VectorSource`, which listens to `addfeature` events i.e. when the interaction ends by double-click, the `addfeature` event is fired. Here, in the `addfeature` callback, I want to transform the geometry of the `LineString` to EPSG:4326 and send the transformed coordinates to an external API which only accepts coordinates with this projection.

However, each time I attempt to transform the coordinates, the drawn `LineString` disappears from the map. Here's the problematic part in the code:

```
source.on('addfeature', function (evt) {
    const {feature} = evt;
    const featureGeometry = feature.getGeometry();
    addFeatureCallback(featureGeometry);
});

function addFeatureCallback(geometry) {
    geometry.transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'); // <-- this removes my drawn feature from the map. If I remove this line, the drawn LineString remains.
    const coords = geometry.getCoordinates();
    ...
}
```

I tried creating a new variable that references the `geometry` param from `addFeatureCallback` and calling the transform method unto it, but the problem still remains and the drawn line disappears. Is there a way to transform the feature geometry to another projection without it removing the `LineString` from the map? As a workaround, I could set the default projection in OL to be `EPSG:4326`, however, this breaks other parts of my project and I would really like to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was that I was modifying the `geometry` in place. Instead of that, now I first `clone()` then do the transform.

Answer here helped - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36134974/transforming-coordinates-of-feature-in-openlayers